# Send variable to php post using jQuery getJSON

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a webpage where I need to dropdowns. When I will select the first dropdown the values in the second drodown will be added, so I need to post the value of first dropdown to the server for generating the sql query.

```
<?php
$catName = $_POST['catname'];


require_once('my_sqli_connect.php');

$sql = "select product_name from products where category_name='$catName'";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, 
        array('product_name'=>$row[0]));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysql_close($con);?>
```

My jquery code

```
$("#selectcat").change( function() {

    $.getJSON(
        '../database/bringproduct.php', 
        'catname='+$('#selectcat').val(),
        function(info){
            $('#bringproduct').empty();

            $.each(info.result, function(){
                $('ul').append('<li>'+this['product_name']+'</li>');
            });
        }); 
    });
```

I tested the php script by giving $catName a default value and deleting the second parameter in getJSON() it is working fine. Can anyone tell me where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a GET request (`$.getJSON`) but expecting POST variables in your PHP: `$catName = $_POST['catname'];`. Change to `$catName = $_GET['catname'];`

Comment: @BelalKhan no problem, could you mark it as the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Can you tell me what to do if I want to send more than one values to the php script??